# Build Network after changing streets feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, error-999999, streets

Previous posts have said a network cannot be created in ModelBuilder. However, I have been able to create a network after going through part of the wizard, but stop short of build network, then go back and edit the streets network.

For some reason, when I iterate through the creation of new streets, I cannot input those new streets into the model. I get an error 99999 and it says the problem is that my "OBJECTID" is all null values, which is the same in my previous work outside of  MB that worked.

How can I execute "build network" after editing the streets feature class?

Comment: Are there null values in your input feature classes?